# Remove new version's placeholder itunes connect

Tags: ios, binary, version, app-store-connect, duplicates

How can I remove the version placeholder on iTunes Connect?
I have uploaded a version on a wrong application and when I realized that I removed the binary but I have never thought of this - can I also delete the placeholder? - because there is no update developed for this app yet.

Image for explanation

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To edit the version number, select the falsely numbered version on the left on iTunes Connect (so NOT the "App Information", but under that the version "1.0.1 Prepare for Submission" etc), scroll down in the right pane to "General App Information" -- just below the App Icon you can see the version number and it's editable! Change it, hit save, and you'll see the version number change on the left side.

(My answer is valid for iTunes Connect web UI as of 5. Jan 2016)

Answer (score 5):

Its not possible to delete a placeholder of a version. But it doesnt affect anything at all so just wait till you are ready to upload 1.1 and update the same version. Or create a new version and work on that (e.g. 2.0). I've had this happen to me a few months ago and I couldn't do much.

Comment: You can change the version number of a placeholder. What's intensely annoying is that if you accidentally delete the screenshots you can't just delete the placeholder and recreate it to have them copied across. (Major pain with multiple localizations).